# How do I get my MenuItems to call a method from a separate class?

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface

I currently have a project with three different classes. I have a driver class (main), a GUI panel with all the button listeners and gui components in and then a third class with the methods the Graphics Panel abides to.

I'm wondering how I would go about getting my JMenuItem "new" to call upon the clear method from my GraphicsPanel class.

**Main Method:**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class guiDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pen Simulator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GUIPanel panel = new GUIPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        // there is a method to set minimum size
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // File Menu
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("New");

        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Load");

        JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Save");

        JMenuItem item4 = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.add(item1);
        fileMenu.add(item2);
        fileMenu.add(item3);
        fileMenu.add(item4);

        // Help Menu

        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        helpMenu.add(about);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); // setting the Frames menubar as the newly
                                    // created menubar
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

**GUIPANEL:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField userCommand;
    private JLabel instruction1;
    private JButton instruct, clear;
    private GraphicsPanel graphics;
    private int penX, penY, angle;
    private int currentDirection = 0;

    private boolean penIsUp = false;
    private Color penColour;

    public GUIPanel() {

        graphics = new GraphicsPanel();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // SOUTH PANEL CONSTRUCTOR
        JPanel command = new JPanel();
        command.setLayout(new BoxLayout(command, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        instruction1 = new JLabel("Enter Command:");

        // BUTTO
        instruct = new JButton("Execute");
        instruct.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        clear = new JButton("Clear Graphics");

        // TEXT FIELD
        userCommand = new JTextField(10);

        command.add(instruction1);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4, 0)));
        command.add(userCommand);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2, 0)));
        command.add(instruct);
        command.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(2, 0)));
        command.add(clear);

        add(command, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(graphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        init();

    }

    public void init() {

        penX = graphics.getWidth() / 2;
        penY = graphics.getHeight() / 2;
    }

    public void moveForward() {

        String command = userCommand.getText().toLowerCase();
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(command.replace("forward ", ""));

        userCommand.setText("");

        if (penIsUp == false) {
            if (currentDirection == 0) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY - distance));
                penY = penY - distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 1) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX + distance, penY);
                penX = penX + distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 2) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY + distance));
                penY = penY + distance;
            }
            if (currentDirection == 3) {
                graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX - distance, penY);
                penX = penX - distance;
            }
            graphics.repaint();

        } else if (penIsUp == true) {
            penY = penY - distance;

        }
    }

    public void moveBackward() {

        String command = userCommand.getText().toLowerCase();
        int distance = Integer.parseInt(command.replace("backward ", ""));

        userCommand.setText("");

        if (penIsUp == false) {
            graphics.drawLine(penColour, penX, penY, penX, (penY + distance));
            graphics.repaint();
            penY = penY + distance;

        } else if (penIsUp == true) {
            penX = penX + distance;
        }

    }

    public void penUp() {
        penIsUp = true;
        userCommand.setText("");
    }

    public void penDown() {
        penIsUp = false;
        userCommand.setText("");
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {

                System.out.println("you typed something");
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("turnleft")) {
                currentDirection = currentDirection - 1;
                if (currentDirection == -1) {
                    currentDirection = 3;
                }
                userCommand.setText("");

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("turnright")) {
                currentDirection = currentDirection + 1;
                if (currentDirection == 4) {
                    currentDirection = 0;
                }
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().startsWith("forward ")) {

                try {
                    moveForward();

                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command");
                }
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().startsWith("backward ")) {

                try {
                    moveBackward();
                }

                catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command");
                }
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {

                penColour = Color.BLACK;
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {

                penColour = Color.GREEN;
                userCommand.setText("");

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {

                penColour = Color.RED;
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("reset")) {

                graphics.clear();
                penX = 0;
                penY = 0;
                userCommand.setText("");
                graphics.repaint();

            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("penUp")) {
                penUp();
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

            else if (userCommand.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("penDown")) {
                penDown();
                userCommand.setText("");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**GraphicsPanel:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * The default BG colour of the image.
     */
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    /**
     * The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous
     * drawing activity is persistent on the panel.
     */
    private BufferedImage image;

    public GraphicsPanel() {

        Dimension resolution = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int width = (int) resolution.getWidth(); // casting the screen width to
                                                    // integer
        int height = (int) resolution.getHeight(); // casting the scren height
                                                    // to integer

        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the
        // image.
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

        clear();

    }

    public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    /**
     * Clears the image contents.
     */
    public void clear() {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Where possible I would also like to be able to add a scroller so that when my drawing goes outside of the graphicspanel it creates a scroller however adding a scroller didn't seem to work for that.

Any help and direction appreciated.

Edit:

```
    item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clear();

        }

    });
```

Comment: 1) Where is `GraphicsPanel` instantiated and added to another component? Never mind. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) This kind of stuff is OOP 101 that should be sorted out long before attempting apps. with a GUI.

Comment: Forgot GUI Panel class, now added

Comment: Which part of 'Minimal' are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: That the minimal part in your link doesn't seem to help people who don't understand how to keep their code minimal and produce the problem. I would rather give the complete code than attempt to ask a question for something I can't get to work. No offense but every question I post you give me a non useful answer on before someone answers it properly with no problems. Bye

Comment: *"That the minimal part in your link doesn't seem to help people who don't understand how to keep their code minimal and produce the problem."* It had to be kept short. The SSCCE document OTOH, gives many good tips on making code shorter so that people don't have to trawl through almost 350 lines of code in order to see where you lost the reference/access to the component in question. *"I would rather give the complete code.."* What your effectively saying in refusing to hone code down is that you consider your time to be more valuable than that of people trying to help you, for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ActionListener` (or use a lambda expression if you are on Java 8 or newer) to your new-button and there call the `clear()` method.

Besides that, you should not override `paint()` but `paintComponent()`.

And to get the `JScrollPane` working correctly, you need to set the preferred size of your panel, either by calling `setPreferredSize()` if the content sizes changes, or maybe by overriding `getPreferredSize()`. Furthermore you need to get the `JScrollPane` to recalculate whether scrollbars are necessary after the preferred size of your panel changed, thus you have to call `revalidate()` on your panel after the preferred size changed.

Comment: Do you mean something like in my edit? I get that the method is undefined

Comment: You are trying to call `clear()` on your `ActionListener` instance. You need to call it on your `GraphicsPanel` instance of course. Now after your edit your `guiDriver` class has no reference to your `GraphicsPanel` class anymore, so either add a forwarding method to your `GUIPanel` class that calls `clear()` on your `GraphicsPanel` class, or add a getter to your `GUIPanel` class that returns the `GraphicsPanel` so that `guiDriver` can get the instance and call `clear()` on it. Which way to go is a question of your architecture.

Comment: Also, anything that involves the GUI should be done on the EDT, so most of the content of the main() method should be done in a new Runnable invoked by SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: So do you mean adding something such as : class getClear{
  
  getClear(){
   graphics.clear();
  }
  
 }

Comment: Maybe you should do some basic Java learning? This is quite basic stuff of object oriented programming. More something like `public void clearGraphics() { graphics.clear(); }` in `GUIPanel` and then calling `panel.clear()` in your `ActionListener`. A new class would be quite senseless.

Comment: Yes I agree. Dont feel like the way I have learnt has been hugely beneficial so have just taken two OO books out that should help me learn. Thanks for your help.